# Parametric Polymorphism in Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, polymorphism, ocaml, parametric-polymorphism

Suppose I have an algebraic data type:

```
type ('a,'b) addition = 
  | first of 'a 
  | second of 'b
```

How could I write two functions below in OCaml that satisfy the polymorphic type signatures above?

```
1: ('a, 'b) addition * ('a -> 'c) * ('b -> 'c) -> 'c

2: ('a, 'b * 'c) addition -> ('a, 'b) addition * ('a, 'c) addition
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. Here's [an open letter](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) for you.

Comment: The types are your friend. Have a good look at them and look what information they already give you about the code. How many arguments does your functions take? Are these arguments tuples? What type do these arguments have? Can you do pattern matching on some arguments? If so, what can you get from this pattern matching? Are some arguments functions? If so, what can you apply them to?